# "Copy to File..." button is disabled in certificate dialog

Tags: windows, certificate, x509

In the certificate details dialog, the button to save it is disabled. Why is that? I remember it working before.

What I did was:

- open a new window of IE (best to close all others first)
- to visit a HTTPS website, like https://www.google.com
- click on the *Certificate* button (next to the URL bar)
- then click "View certificates"
- see picture below

It is the same on Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 , both using IE11.

Example:

[image: Screenshot]

*Addendum:*

I tried Chrome on the same PC and there the button is available. See screenshot, the left dialog is opened by clicking the padlock icon in Chrome and the right one by doing the same in IE:

[image]

PS: I'll use Firefox until then... (or Chrome)

Comment: I can't repro this. Did you try [How to repair or reinstall Internet Explorer in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/318378)

Comment: Are you sure? I tried on 4 different PCs. Did you follow step by step what I did? For example try https://www.google.com (it may redirect to a country site, does not matter)

Comment: Yes. I'm sure. In fact I tried with google.com. I clicked on the padlock, then view certificates.

Comment: You need to run as Admin

Comment: As in the nineties? ;) Actual Admin user or any user with admin rights?

Comment: Try both. I'm not completely sure it's the answer for IE 11 but it was for IE 8 http://certificate.fyicenter.com/384_IE_Internet_Explorer__Export_Web_Site_Server_Certificate_in.html

Comment: Most likely depends on where the certificates are saved on the browser. Starting Internet Exploder in Adminisbreaker mode would probably fix the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> You need to run as Admin – DavidPostill

@DavidPostill's comments resolve same issue for me. After I run IE as admin, I can copy the website certificate to a file.

Comment: This worked like a charm, but it seems ridiculous. I cannot understand why IE was designed this way. It totally makes sense to require admin privilege to *install* a cert, but why would *exporting* a cert be sensitive?? Aren't certificates just public information?